# Pool + ZFS Folder size not matching in OpenIndiana & Napp-IT

Tags: zfs, openindiana

I created a 59.7TB Pool with 8x RAIDZ2, 8x RAIDZ2, 6x RAIDZ2, 2x Spare (3TB HD)
The pool shows up at 59.7TB. This is exactly what I expected. Then I go to create a ZFS Folder and it says I only have 41.1TB available. Whats going on? The link below is a screenshot of the ZFS Folder creation in Napp-IT.

http://cl.ly/Kid3

Side question, these are the speeds I'm getting. Is this good? Should I be doing something to optimize it?
20.48 GB in 70s = 292.57 MB/s Write
20.48 GB in 30.5s = 671.48 MB/s Read

Thanks

*EDIT*

`zpool list` returns

`NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT`

`backup  59.8T   147G  59.6T         -     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -`

`rpool     74G  3.42G  70.6G         -     4%  1.00x  ONLINE  -`

Comment: What is the output of `zpool list`? Also, from your description I gather you have 16 3TB disks of usable space; if you convert from disk manufacturers' TB's (1000^4 bytes) to regular TB's (1024^4 bytes) you have to multiply by a factor of roughly .91, which brings the pool's usable size to something like 43.7 TB.

Comment: added zpool list to initial question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's clear now.

That happens because `zpool list` reports the total size and free space of all your storage space, without taking into account that you asked for redundancy. In fact, 22*3*1000^4/1024^4 amounts to 60.0, which sounds close enough to 59.8 (I don't know the exact size of the 3 TB disks).

On the contrary, `zfs list` (and the screenshot you linked) report the available space after taking redundancy into account.

For a few examples, look at this FAQ: [Why doesn't the space that is reported by the zpool list command and the zfs list command match?](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/faq/#HWhydoesn27tthespacethatisreportedbythezpoollistcommandandthezfslistcommandmatch3F)